# Brainfuck compiler in scala

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, interpreter, brainfuck

Want to make some Domain Specific Language(DSL) for practice, first idea it is to write interpreter or compiler of [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck). 
First idea was to override functions such as they will behave as Brainfuck commands: `">"`, `"<"`, `"+"`, `"-"`, `"."`, `","`, `"["`, `"]"`. Unfortunately you cannot decalare function as `"."`.

Is there better solution to write it in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say this specifically in your question, but it seems that when you say DSL, you mean [Internal DSL](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InternalDslStyle.html)?

Internal DSLs are great, but fundamentally you're always limited by the syntax of the language you're trying to use. Scala is a particularly good language for writing an internal DSL, because it has a simple and flexible syntax. But it's not infinitely flexible.

Other avenues you might want to explore might be:

1. Choose a different symbol instead of ".". Scala can support Unicode identifiers, so if you fancy going down that road, perhaps you could use "∙"?
2. Create an [External DSL](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html) instead?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that you are aware of this [example](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5372).

Also this [example](http://peter-braun.org/2012/07/brainfuck-interpreter-in-40-lines-of-scala/) suggested by [Mikaël Mayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287856/mikael-mayer) in comments.

Comment: I don't know, I just recall that particular example from the Scala official site.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a BrainFuck interpreter that makes use of Scala parser combinators. the source code is [here](https://github.com/antoinecomte/bfi/blob/master/src/net/antoinecomte/bfi/Interpreter.scala) if it may help.